# Find the next number in the following sequence: 109080, 12123, 1350, 153

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

I came across this sequence in [the paper](https://www.pressreader.com/uk/daily-mail/20190420/283824329958108):

> 109080, 12123, 1350, 153, ?

What could be the next number? And what is the pattern that connects these numbers?

Dividing a term by the next term leads to a number which consecutively decreases from 8.99 for the first term to 8.8 for the third term Is that of any use?

Comment: It’s from [the Daily Mail, April 20](https://www.pressreader.com/uk/daily-mail/20190420/283824329958108)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 20

Because

> If you compute one term minus nine times the next one, you always get $-27$. In other words: $$x_{i+1}=\frac{x_i+27}9 \,\, \left(\text{or $\frac{x_i}9+3$}\right)$$
>  Note that $20$ is the last integer in this sequence, because it falls under $9$ at the next step.

Comment: @Vin You're welcome. Actually, the last observation you made in the puzzle is the reason why I tried that. Think about what is natural and close to 8.99...

Comment: Or $x_n = (133*9^n+27)/8$ for $n=4,3,2,1,0$